# How to start iperf3 server in UDP mode?

Tags: bandwidth, udp, iperf

I would like to test UDP connectivity with `iperf3` but do not know how to start it in UDP server mode.

`iperf3 -s` only opens a TCP socket:

```
root@srv ~# lsof -i -P | grep iperf3
iperf3    21030            root    3u  IPv4 15606995      0t0  TCP *:5201 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is a bit different for `iperf3`. Example 1Mbps udp test:

server side:

```
iperf3 --server
```

client side:

```
iperf3 --udp --client client.ip.address --bitrate 1M
```

What I find really interesting is the server-side doesn't start listening on the udp port until it receives the first incoming udp packet. This is weirdly unintuitive.

Comment: I guess most people reckon the typo isn't worth mentioning, but for beginners, the client side command should specify the **server** ip address: `iperf3 --udp --client server.ip.address --bitrate 1M`

Answer (score 2):

You can open UDP socket in the port 5003 using the below command.

```
iperf3 -s -p 5003
```

Comment: This is the same command I used in my question. This said, I checked a client with `-u` and the UDP connection is successful. It means that both TCP and UDP ports are opened automatically.